# Almost full screen iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I need a way to fill almost the entire page with the iframe. But as you can see here, there is a big white space after the iframe:

http://jsfiddle.net/mW9WF/896/

How can I remove the whitespace ?
This is my code:

```
<div class="header" >
    &nbsp;
</div>
    <iframe class="mainBody" src="http://www.repubblica.it/tecnologia/2015/07/16/news/cellulari_e_tariffe_estive_gigabyte_extra_e_servizi_di_intrattenimento_ecco_le_offerte-119221137/"></iframe>

<div class="footer">
    &nbsp;
</div>


body {
    margin:0;
}

.header {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: red;
}

.mainBody {
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 20px;
    width:100%;
}

.content {
    color:#fff;
}

.footer {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: blue;

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`top` and `bottom` css attributes are not ment to go together in the same rule. my suggestion is to set the `iframe`, `html` and `body` tags `width` and `height` to `100%` and set a `padding` to the boddy in order to get the desired space between the viewport limits.

```
.mainBody, html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    padding: 5%;
}
```

The white space after your iframe is due to the `bottom: 20px;` attribute in your `.mainBody` rule.

If you want the white space to be fixed no matter the viewport size, you can change the `padding` from `px` to `%`. Also, if you don't want the white space from all sides to be the same, remember that padding can be set to 4 values (`padding: 40px 10px 20px 10px;`)